# Yii very weird save() behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have encountered something very, very weird. Working in VirtualBox, Ubuntu, Apache2, PHP, MySQL I got some very strange behaviour from one particular model.

I wanted to add ability to enter multiple language versions of the same string, say product name. I used jQuery to make nice tabs with languages and created temporary array to store all that information, used CActiveForm widget to collect and present data.

```
<?php foreach($languages as $language): ?>
  <div id="tab_<?=$language->code?>">
    <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($model,"translations[$language->code][name]",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,"translations[$language->code][name]"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
 [...]
```

So this is how I collect data into a $translations array. This is my $translations array:

```
$translations = array(
  'name' => 'NewName',
  'sub_name' => 'Subname'
);
```

Then I obviously assign it to a proper model in Controler action:

```
[...]
foreach ($translations as $key => $value){
  $x = new Translations();
  $x->language = $key;
  $x->id = $product->id;
  $x->name = $value['name'];
  $x->sub_name = $value['sub_name']
  $x->save();
}
[...]
```

Now there are also other fields that are only one per product:

```
[...]
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'something'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'something',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,"something"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And those are stored simply by

```
$product->save();
```

Everything is in a neat transaction.

HOWEVER....

What I get in result is like this (join on translations and product table):

```
id       name        subname        something
1        NewN
2        NewName     S
3        NewName     Subname        Som
4        NewName     Subname        Something
```

4 records when I only add ONE.... and more text I put in, more records are created. Split by random number of characters, sometimes as little as 4 sometimes as much as 12. This is repeatable but not always.... I am totaly dumbstruck by this behaviour.

Anyone ever saw anything like this and can shed ANY light on it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the query you use to get the "join on translations and product table", and how/where you're viewing the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be coming in at many stages:

- the form
- the controller
- binding the data from the form to the model
- the model saving (ActiveRecord)
- or even the database

So 'divide and conquer' your problem.

**MySQL**

Turn on your 'general mysql log' to see the queries that are being sent to MySQL. If they look like the weird forms you are seeing above, then it's not the database. It's unlikely you'll have any problems at this stage, but it's good to rule it out.

**ActiveRecord**

Then hardcode your values into the model. In your controller, just create an instance of the model and save it. Does that replicate the problem you're having? If so, it's a problem with your implementation of ActiveRecord. Try removing the relationships and work on that.

**Controller**

There could be something weird in your controller. Again, hardcode the data that you want to pass to the model when you create the instance.

**Binding**

It could be a problem with how you are binding data from the form to the model. Manually set the values of the form, then bind that data to the model as normal.

This is where back-end testing can really help you, as you can isolate what's working from what's not. Look into tools like Behat and PHPUnit.

Comment: Man, you are a saviour :). I got mysql log running and it seems that it generates proper queries... I mean there are 3 queries executed - one to add product, one to add two different translations. What does that mean? MySQL is somehow acting up?

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash It sounds like your relations are not configured correctly. Go back to the documentation, get it working at the simplest level. Use migrations to automate the recreation of the database, and insert some fixtures **using the model**. Keep playing around until you can see that the fixtures are being saved properly.